# How to add a custom splash that dissapears after a custom time to allow for webview to load. Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

I'm using this code to show a splash screen but the only thing I see is black.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
SplashViewController *splash = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splash"];
splash.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
splash.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self.window addSubview:splash.view];
```

The view controller of the splash screen is loading because the break points are being called but I cant see the view controller I just see black.

Comment: Have you tried doing i.e. splash.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; to see if it isn't actually your splash appearing, just black? Also, why use modal transition and presentation style when you just add subview?

Comment: Il try that but I do have a UIImage in the splash screen that should be showing.

Comment: Its something with my UIImageView. Its not showing the image for some reason.

Comment: Make sure you're loading image with the right name, try looking for typos. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of adding `splash.view` as `window` subview you can use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to present the splash view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using storyboard, so this is what you can do:

```
- Add view controller (VC0) to storyboard
- Set correct orientation on VC0 - your app orientation
- Add container view on VC0 (full size view)
- Add splash screen image on VC0 (full size view)
- Create UIViewController subclass - call it for example CustomSplashDisplay
- create UIImageView IBOutlet - for example vwImage
- override viewDidLoad like:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self performSelector:@selector(HideImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:kSplashScreenDuration];
}

-(void)HideImage
{
    [vwImage setHidden:YES];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:vwImage];
}
```

in storyboard

```
- Set VC0 as initial view controller
- Set its class to CustomSplashDisplay
- connect UIImage outlet
- embed previous initial view controller in container view
```

run an here you go...